# How to apply local styles / JS to UIWebview after loading a URL

Tags: iphone, css, uiwebview

I am loading a web page in my iPhone app. However the page is not mobile optimized. So, I would like to customize some elements from the page like remove sidebar etc.

For doing this, I guess, some CSS / JS need to be injected into the page to modify the page. Can this be done ? If yes, how to?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others having same question:

It can be done by using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method of UIWebView (upon webViewDidFinishLoad)

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('topBarBody').remove();"];
}
```